# The importance of girth when embedding graphs on surfaces

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-topology

I want to know how to find largest $n$ that $K_n$ ( complete graph on n vertices)
can be embedded into torus ( $\Sigma_1$ ) and projective plane ( $ \Pi_1 $ )

I found a "proof" in  [this paper](http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~chris/topology/CHAP05%20Graphs%20on%20Surfaces.pdf) on page 7.

They use formula $\frac{2E}{F}>g$ where g is girth = length of the shortest cycle.

I don't understand how is  girth related to embedding,

can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is when you embed a graph on a surface, the girth of the graph becomes the smallest number of edges that a face of the embedding can have. So when you are counting vertices, edges, and faces (Euler characteristic) to determine if a graph can be embedded on a surface or not, it's helpful to relate the number of edges and the number of faces. This relation is the girth, where

$$2E >gF$$